# Como hallar cuantas comparaciones realiza una función de búsqueda?

Tags: python, lista, pycharm, busqueda

Mi función tiene que hallar su posición y luego decirme cuantas comparaciones realizó la función para llegar a la respuesta:                                   Lista de numeros: [1,2,3,4,5] Numero a buscar: 10 El numero 10 no se encuentra despues de 3 comparacion(es)

```
def busquedad(valor, lista):
    indice = -1
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        if valor == lista[i]:
            indice = i

    if indice == -1:
        print("El numero NO esta en la lista luego de" , ******,"comparaciones")
    else:
        print("El numero esta en la lista luego de" , ******,"comparaciones"))
    return indice
```

Comment: Tu código hace exactamente `len(lista) + 1` comparaciones. Siempre. Hace `len(lista)` comparaciones en el ciclo, y una comparación más cuando preguntas si `indice == -1`

Comment: Hola, esto se encuentra en el enunciado: Escribe una función en Python que permita saber si un número se encuentra en una lista ordenada. Si el numero a buscar se encuentra o no en la lista, entonces se deber´a mostrar un mensaje apropiado. Adicionalmente, deberá contar el número de comparaciones hechas por su algoritmo. El número total de comparaciones debe ser menor al tamaño de la lista de números y puede asumir que la lista tiene como mınimo 5 elementos.

Comment: Tu código no cumple el enunciado: no importa lo que busques, siempre recorre la lista completa. Te falta un `break` cuando encuentras el valor.

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta no es respondible, no tiene un problema en especifico. Se adjunta código con un enunciado, pero no se adjunta el por que se realizo ese código. En fin, le faltan muchos detalles. @personaquetratadeprogramar

Answer (score 1):

Espero haberte entendido, si quiere contar cuantas comparaciones hizo  hasta dar con el numero incluyendo la comparación que da con el numero seria algo así:

```
    def busquedad(valor, lista):
    indice = -1
    contador=0
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        if valor == lista[i]:
            indice = i
            contador+=1
            break
        contador+=1

    if indice == -1:
        print("El numero ",str(valor), " NO esta en la lista luego de " , str(contador)," comparaciones")
    else:
        print("El numero ",str(valor), " esta en la lista luego de" , str(contador),"comparaciones")
    return indice

lista=[12,45,3,6,8,98,54,232]
print("Posicion: ",busquedad(3,lista))
```

ahora si lo que quieres es saber la cantidad de comparaciones sin contar la ultima comparación que es igual al numero buscado seria de esta forma(simplemente sacando el contador dentro del `if(){}` ):

```
    def busquedad(valor, lista):
    indice = -1
    contador=0
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        if valor == lista[i]:
            indice = i
            
            break
        contador+=1

    if indice == -1:
        print("El numero ",str(valor), " NO esta en la lista luego de " , str(contador)," comparaciones")
    else:
        print("El numero ",str(valor), " esta en la lista luego de" , str(contador),"comparaciones")
    return indice

lista=[12,45,3,6,8,98,54,232]
print("Posicion: ",busquedad(3,lista))
```

Comment: El OP no hace `break` después de encontrar el valor. Por tanto, el número de comparaciones es fijo e igual al largo de la lista. Tampoco necesitas un contador aparte si deseas agregar el `break`; la expresión `i + 1` te da el número de comparaciones efectuadas. La variable `indice` es redundante; basta comparar `if i == len(lista):` para detectar que no lo encontraste. El código perfecto es aquel donde no queda nada por eliminar.

Comment: Hola, esto se encuentra en el enunciado:  Escribe una función en Python que permita saber si un número se encuentra en una lista ordenada. Si el numero a buscar se encuentra o no en la lista, entonces se deber´a mostrar un mensaje apropiado. Adicionalmente, deber´a contar el número de comparaciones hechas por su algoritmo. El número total de comparaciones debe ser menor al tamaño de la lista de números y puede asumir que la lista tiene como m´ınimo 5 elementos.

Comment: @personaquetratadeprogramar Tu código no cumple el enunciado; el de Santiago, si.

Comment: Lo sé, por esa razón dije que quería  ayuda. Además el de Santiago me recorre toda la lista, yo necesito uno que empiece en la mitad.

Comment: @CandidMoe así Lista de palabras: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90] Numero a buscar: 50 El numero 50 se encuentra despues de 1 comparacion(es)

Comment: Estaría bien que explicaras por cuales razones el código original de OP estaba incorrecto, y justifiques esos cambios. De cualquier manera el OP nunca aclara que duda/problema tiene. **Es solo recomendación** @Santiago.

Answer (score 0):

Este es un comentario con código.

La cuestión de fondo es que el número de comparaciones en el código del OP es fijo e igual al largo de la lista, dado que falta un `break` después de encontrar el valor buscado dentro de la lista.

Nota: El OP pone "*****" en la impresión, donde se supone que pone la cuenta. Como `indice` es la única variable mencionada, eso pondré para que la función compile.

Si ejecuto la función del OP:

```
busquedad(50,  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
```

obtengo como resultado:

```
El numero esta en la lista luego de 4 comparaciones
```

Lo que está bien y mal. Está mal porque el mensaje está mal formulado. Lo que la función encuentra es el **indice** donde está el valor, no el número de comparaciones que hizo. Esta ... bien ... porque al menos dice en que posición lo encontró.

De acuerdo con el resultado, el mensaje correcto sería:

```
El numero esta en la lista en el indice 4.
```

Modifiquemos el código para que cuente las comparaciones y ejecutemoslo de nuevo. Vamos a incrementar un contador después de cada comparación (innecesario, realmente, como veremos más adelante). Todo lo demás se conserva tal cual:

```
def busquedad(valor, lista):
    indice = -1
    comparaciones = 0
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        if valor == lista[i]:
            indice = i
        comparaciones += 1

    print("Se realizaron %d comparaciones" % comparaciones)
    
    if indice == -1:
        print("El numero NO esta en la lista luego de" , indice,"comparaciones")
    else:
        print("El numero esta en la lista luego de" , indice,"comparaciones")
    return indice

busquedad(50,  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
```

produce:

```
Se realizaron 9 comparaciones
El numero esta en la lista luego de 4 comparaciones
```

**Código optimo**

Esta versión del código cuenta correctamente las comparaciones realizadas.

```
def busquedad(valor, lista):
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        if valor == lista[i]:
            break

    i += 1  # Transformar indice en cuenta.
    if i == len(lista):
        print("El numero NO esta en la lista luego de" , i, "comparaciones")
    else:
        print("El numero esta en la lista luego de " , i,"comparaciones")
    return i

busquedad(50,  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
busquedad(0,  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
busquedad(100,  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
busquedad(10, [1,2,3,4,5])
```

Produce:

```
El numero esta en la lista luego de  5 comparaciones
El numero NO esta en la lista luego de 8 comparaciones
El numero NO esta en la lista luego de 8 comparaciones
El numero NO esta en la lista luego de 5 comparaciones
```

Comment: Hola, me sigue saliendo incorrecto, tú código está correcto pero al momento de realizar el otro ejemplo me sale diferente.                                                                                      Lista de numeros: [1,2,3,4,5]  ///  Numero a buscar: 10 ///  El numero 10 no se encuentra despues de 3 comparacion(es)                           
Lista de palabras: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]   /// Numero a buscar: 50                                                                                      
El número 50 se encuentra despues de 1 comparacion(es)

Comment: @personaquetratadeprogramar. Sin ver el código que estas ejecutando, no puedo opinar. Edite la respuesta para agregar el caso de buscar "10" en [1,2,3,4,5], que puedes ver arroja 5 comparaciones. La búsqueda de "50" ya está considerada en mi respuesta.

Comment: He utilizado el código tu código pero me sigue saliendo 5 comparaciones y debo optimizarlo a: ** Escribe una función en Python que permita saber si un número se encuentra en una lista ordenada. Si el numero a buscar se encuentra o no en la lista, entonces se deber´a mostrar un mensaje apropiado. Adicionalmente, deber´a contar el número de comparaciones hechas por su algoritmo. El número total de comparaciones debe ser menor al taman˜o de la lista de números y puede asumir que la lista tiene como m´ınimo 5 elementos. **

Comment: @personaquetratadeprogramar. Si el valor no está en la lista, la búsqueda lineal la recorrera completa, lo que son 5 comparaciones. Si quieres optimizar la búsqueda necesitas otro algoritmo, como [búsqueda binaria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BAsqueda_binaria). Esto no es parte de la pregunta planteada.

Comment: Como sería con búsqueda binaria? @CandidMoe

Comment: @Candid Moe el link que adjuntas ofrece información valiosa, conceptos acerca de la búsqueda binaria. Estaría mejor que adjuntaras un link que responda al problema del OP, ese link no ofrece una manera de implementarlo a Python. **Es solo recomendación**